# JMeter logging in console and log viewer simultaneously

Tags: logging, jmeter, log4j

Newbie question

Using JSR223 PostProcessor

How does one log to both at the same time?

Want to avoid duplicating messages.

```
out.println("WARNING")
log.warn("WARNING")
```

Have a ton of post processing scripts using log.warn and I need these messages to show up in console at the same time. Been searching like mad and cannot find anything about using one log to output to both. Maybe some way to make each log.warn into a out.println using a pre-processor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

#### Print the message everytime the warn is logged:

- use a method that makes both operations:

  ```
  public static void printAndLog(Logger log, String message) {
      System.out.println(message)
      log.warn(message)
  }
  ```
- use aspects from AspectJ

#### Use 2 appenders in log4j (one for console, one for file)

This is applicable if logging a message to the console (STDOUT) is an accepted alternative to `System.out.println`.

- adjust log4j.properties:

  ```
  log4j.rootLogger=INFO,CONSOLE,FILE
  log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender    
  log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
  ```
- adjust log4j2.xml

  ```
  <Configuration status="INFO">
      <Appenders>
          <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
              <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n" />
          </Console>
          <File name="FILE" ...>
              <PatternLayout pattern="..."/>
          </File>
      </Appenders>
      <Loggers>
          <Root level="info">
              <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
              <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
          </Root>
      </Loggers>
  </Configuration>
  ```

Comment: set log4j properties: would that be in user/jmeter/system properties?

Comment: 'javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script144.groovy: 3: Apparent variable 'OUT' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context. You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling. You attempted to use a method 'OUT' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.  @ line 3, column 5. OUT.println(message)'

Comment: Thinking there must be some way to throw every WARN to console

Comment: @J.Doe, that properties file is not mandatory. You can find an XML instead.
Regarding the "out", you can replace it explicitly by "System.out" and it will work.

Another option would be to to use aspects.

Comment: log4j.properties and log42j.xml worked, cant seem to get method that makes both operations to work, preprocessor or postprocessor

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

Added the following to log4j2.xml located in bin folder of JMeter

```
<Appenders>

<File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}" append="false">
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
</File>

<GuiLogEvent name="gui-log-event">
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
</GuiLogEvent>

<Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
</Console>
```

and

```
<Loggers>

<Root level="info">
  <AppenderRef ref="jmeter-log" />
  <AppenderRef ref="gui-log-event" />
  <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
</Root>
```

Wouldn't have found the answer without @romania_engineer